# websphere jython scripts cannot access AdminTask

Tags: scripting, websphere

We have an auto-deployment script that uses wsadmin and jython. The script appears to work as expected however after 6-7 redeployments the AdminTask object becomes unavilable, resulting in the following error when we attempt to use that object:

```
WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node ukdlniqa41Node01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
WASX8011W: AdminTask object is not available.
...   
Traceback (innermost last):
   File "<string>", line 251, in ?
   File "<string>", line 14, in main
   File "<string>", line 38, in initialize
NameError: AdminTask
```

My question is, what would cause this AdminTask object to become unavailable? (it remains unavailable until we restart the server instance)

Answer (score 1):

AdminTask may be available if one of the previous tasks does not finish properly. This happens often especially if your server is in development mode. I would suggest gathering Deployment Mustgather as per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&context=SSCR4XA&q1=MustGatherDocument&uid=swg21199344&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en and submitting the results to IBM.